# Adding two matrices prints a column of garbage data c++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading

I'm trying to add two matrices using multidimensional arrays and overloading the addition operator '+' and the assignment operator '=' however, garbage data is passed to my overloaded assignment operator function.

I've been reading things about the Copy and Swap Idioms and so on but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem, and I'd prefer to use + and = separately, rather than '+=' which I've seen some people do, because I will use other arithmetic for matrices, but I want to get this solved first.

Here is my header:

```cpp
#ifndef Matrix_h
#define Matrix_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Matrix
{
private:
    int row;
    int column;
    double  ** elements;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int r, int c); //constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& src);  //copy constructor
    ~Matrix(); //destructor

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& right);  // assignment operator
    int getRow() const;
    int getColumn() const;
    void setElement(int r, int c, double data);
    double getElement(int r, int c) const;
    Matrix& operator+(const Matrix& right); // calculates the sum of two matrices

};

#endif
```

Here are my function definitions:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include "matrix.h"
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c){ //defines the constructor to create a new matrix
    row = r;
    column = c;
    elements = new double*[row];
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        elements[i] = new double[column];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
            elements[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& src){ //defines the copying constructor
    row = src.row;
    column = src.column;
    elements = new double*[row];
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        elements[i] = new double[column];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
            elements[i][j] = src.elements[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix() { //defines the destructor
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        delete[] elements[i];
    }

    delete[] elements;
};

void Matrix::setElement(int r, int c, double data) {
    elements[r][c] = data;
};

double Matrix::getElement(int r, int c) const {
    return elements[r][c];
}

int Matrix::getColumn() const {
    return column;
}

int Matrix::getRow() const {
    return row;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator =(const Matrix& right) {

    if(this->elements != right.elements && column==right.column && row==right.row)
    {
        memcpy ( &this->elements, &right.elements, sizeof(this->elements) );
     }

    return *this;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator +(const Matrix& right) {
    // first, make sure matrices can be added. if not, return original matrix
    if (this->row != right.row || this->column != right.column){
        cout << "Matrix sizes do not match.";
        return (*this);
    }

    Matrix sum(row, column);
    for (int i=0; i<this->row; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<this->column; j++){
            sum.elements[i][j] = this->elements[i][j] + right.elements[i][j];

        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My main simply creates matrixA with a 4x4 matrix of 1s and matrixB with a 4x4 matrix of 2s and adds them where the sum = matrixC which should result in a 4x4 matrix of 3s. However, this is my result:

```
matrixA
1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   

matrixB
2   2   2   2   
2   2   2   2   
2   2   2   2   
2   2   2   2   

matrixC before addition
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   

matrixC after addition
1.0147e-316 3   3   3   
1.0147e-316 3   3   3   
1.0147e-316 3   3   3   
1.0147e-316 3   3   3
```

When I test it to see what elements are passed to 'right' in the '=' function I noticed similar data as the first column of matrixC. I believe I'm not understanding the passing of references involved here fully so I'd like some help on that.

Comment: Are you able to use http://eigen.tuxfamily.org ? It will save some headaches if you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: At least one problem: in `operator =`, `memcpy` is not used correctly. It must be used for a set of contiguous elements, and you must indicate the exact number of bytes, which you don't obtain with `sizeof()` here.

Comment: Yea I have a version that's just straight `elements[i][j] = right.elements[i][j];` and that works so I can refer back to that. @Damien

Comment: @Tzalumen I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment operator is broken (and logically flawed).

It's logically flawed because an assignment like `m1 = m2` should result in `m1 == m2`, no matter what the previous state of `m1` was. Your implementation only attempts to copy when they have the same size. You should resize the matrix on the left side of the assignment.

Your operator also isn't using `memcpy` correctly. `memcpy(dest, src, count)` will copy **contiguous** data from the address `src` to the address `dest`. The addresses you're providing are the *addresses of pointers to pointers to int*, **not** pointers to a contiguous block of `int`s. There are two levels of indirection here that `memcpy` simply has no clue about. Also, `sizeof(this->elements)` is `sizeof(int**)`, which will be a constant of probably 4 or 8 bytes, which should also seem wrong. To fix this, I would just use a plain old set of `for` loops.

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& other){
    // attempt to acquire memory before modifying (for exception safety)
    int** temp = new int*[other.row];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.row; ++i){
        temp[i] = new int[other.col];
    }

    // cleanup
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
        delete[] elements[i];
    }
    delete[] elements;

    // copy data
    elements = temp;
    row = other.row;
    col = other.col;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j){
            elements[i][j] = other.elements[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this
}
```

Another important note: Your `operator+` returns a *reference to a local variable*. This is very bad, but [C++ doesn't protect you from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). You should just return `sum` by value.

In modern C++, we generally prefer to use safer alternatives to manual memory management like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, which go a long way to seamlessly enforce correct usage and to save you from yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seemed to work, the use of `vector` I've read would be ideal but this is an assignment I'm helping out with so I didn't want to stray too far from what was assigned. So you created a new memory space and copy it into `this`? What's the purpose of cleaning `this` before?

Comment: @KristinVernon the purpose of destroying the old data and allocating new data is to account for different sizes of matrices. For example, to copy a 10x10 matrix into a 3x3 matrix, you need to make that 3x3 matrix bigger to avoid reading memory incorrectly. The reason I allocate memory before modifying is for [exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). It's admittedly unlikely that `new` will throw, but it might in some cases, and this ensures that the matrix is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, my CLang compiler warns me that `operator +(const Matrix& right)` return a reference to a temporary which is Undefined Behaviour.

You must return a plain object and not a reference:

```
Matrix operator=(const Matrix& right);  // assignment operator
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator +(const Matrix& right) {
    // ...

    Matrix sum(row, column);
    // ...
    return sum;
}
```

You're returning a reference to an automatic local (`sum`).

You can see the canonical forms of the arithmetic operators [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), and addition should look like

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &b) const;
```

There are various other issues, some mentioned in other answers, but the only thing your current `operator+` reliably produces is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Changing from `Matrix&` to `Matrix` gives me an error like: "double free or corruption (out)"

Comment: Yeah, I said there were other problems too. This is the first one I spotted,  and it's already sufficient that addition would never work. The assignment operator is also wrong, at least.

Comment: @KristinVernon That's because your `operator=` isn't implemented correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: if you store the matrix as one array `double m[rows * columns]` the implementation is going to be much simpler.

Indexing `[row][column]` is `m[row * columns + column]`.

Summing is just summing two arrays element-wise (vector sum essentially).

Comment: Yea this is the format I was given however, so I wanted to stick to it.